# How to destroy the php session with one button

Tags: php, html, session, logout, destroy

I'd like to make a simple form button which completely destroys the session when you click on it. I am just starting to use PHP for the first time, and do not see how I implement it into my HTML code.

What I'd like is simply a form button which will clear the session (and possibly an explanation as to how it works)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The form button is just like any other form button, nothing special.  Catch the POST on the php side of things, and use session_destroy(); to kill the session data entirely.

See this guide for info about forms and post if you're hazy on the subject: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php and this http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php for info about sessions

More info about forms and PHP and how to work with the data from the form: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php

Example:

Order.html:

```
<html><body>
<h4>Tizag Art Supply Order Form</h4>
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body></html>
```

process.php:

```
<html><body>
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
</body></html>
```

It's cheesy...does this help?

Comment: This is correct, but I think the person is asking for you to write the code for them. If not, my mistake. +1 though.

Comment: Not a problem..give me a minute :-D

Comment: That's definitely more than a minute... ;-)

Comment: Not so much write the code as explain where the php gets put (I don't know if I'm making much sense). I saw the short code 

<?php

session_start();

session_destroy();

?>

but do not know where it gets put or how to call it. I tried putting it in an external .php file, and using action= to call it, but my browser simply tries to open the php file when I try clicking this.

Comment: Sorry, i was having fun trying to figure out how to color format code in SO...relatively new here :-S

Comment: Ahh, Tom, are you running your code in a PHP enabled webserver?  or just trying to open it with Internet Explorer/Firefox?

Comment: Do take your time, I really appreciate this.

Comment: Right, so you'll need something like XAMPP.  http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

This installs a local copy of apache and everything you need to get going.

Store your scripts/programs in the htdocs sub-folder under the XAMPP folder.
Then access the script using http://localhost/folder/script.php in your Browser. Be certain that the XAMPP Apache Server is running before calling the script. You can tell via the XAMPP control panel.  :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. You just saved about a day's worth of me trying to figure out why this wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

#### index.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<form action="clear-session.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Clear session" />
</form>
```

#### clear-session.php

```php
session_start();

session_destroy();
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
```

Comment: Nice. To further enhance this, how can i print a messsae saying "Session Cleared!" on the page header ?

Comment: Check if the session exists using the `if else` condition.