# logging out a user completely from a website

Tags: php, session

I have  a `PHP login` and log out script and what I'm trying to achieve  is that when the user click on the log out link he completely logs out, regardless clicking the back button of the browser, and do not want the user to access the page.they should be redirected to the `login` page

this is login function

```
function loggedin() {
    if ( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id']) ) {
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this is my logout script

```
<?php
include 'includes/connect.php';
include 'includes/functions.php';

session_destroy();
header('location: index.php');

?>
```

how can i achieve this??

Comment: When the user accesses a page, check whether the session is set. If the session is not set, redirect him to the login page.

Comment: That depends on how you want to achieve that. For example, in your question, it remains undefined what constitutes a login at all. You need to clarify that otherwise it's just guessing.

Comment: Are you asking about *"How to destroy a session in PHP*"? Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113223/how-to-destroy-the-php-session-with-one-button? - What did you try so far of the many existing material we have on site already? Please reference and make clear which part concretely does not work from it for you specifically. If you have not tried anything of the existing solutions, do that now first.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete all cookies

```php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#73484

And if you have an array of cookie names used for login authentication, you should iterate the cycle only with them.

Comment: i should put this in my logout script

Answer (score 2):

The question was *logging out a user completely from a website* and not just *how do I destroy a PHP session*, so my answer will be somewhat more complex.

Since you're using PHP's `$_SESSION` functionality to handle the user sessions, you can, in particular, tie the current session IDs to the user accounts. Then you can easily force the session to expire.

For example, create a new field in the user database, and call it `active_session_id` or something. Every time a user logs in, save the [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) output to it. Then inside of your `loggedin()` function check if the [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) of the current request matches the one saved when the user was logging in, and if it does not match, the function will return false, so this is how you virtually end a user session. I.e. even though it will still actually be there, it will not be valid anymore.

It is worth noting that the solution above would be sort of a `one-to-one` relation, i.e. one user will be able to have only one active session. If you want to allow users to come from different places at the same time, you'll have to maintain a `one-to-many` relation there by creating a new table called e.g. `users_sessions` and saving the session IDs there. Please do not create another fields in the current users table like `active_session_id_1`, `active_session_id_2` etc. because it is not considered to be a good practice.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can write a generic function that checks if a user is logged in, if not just redirect them like this

```
function isLoggedIn(){

    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){

        //do what you want

    } else{
        header("location:youloginpage.php");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify more on your question, we can only procede by assumptions. Anyway, since you are using that SESSION, and it's not clear if you want to destroy the data contained or not, the function to check if user is logged in, could be modified this way:

```
function loggedin() {
    if ( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['user_id']) && ($_SESSION['user_id'] > 0) ) {
        return true; //user is logged in
        //other operations to be performed
    } else{
        return false; //user is NOT logged in
        //other operations to be performed
    }
}
```

The logout function could just be something like this:

```
function logout() {
    if ( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['user_id']) && ($_SESSION['user_id'] > 0) ) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = -1; //"unsets" the user, while not destroyng session
    } else{
        return false; //user is already logged out - do nothing
    }
}
```